# 'System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException' occurred in System.Windows.ni.dll

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, windows-phone-8

Sir i m developing WP 8.1 app where i m utilizing WCF service but when i run my app it gives me the following exception:
"An unhandled exception of type 'System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException' occurred in System.Windows.ni.dll Additional information: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation".
here is my IService1.cs method:

```
[OperationContract]
string Insert_ChallanDetails(Insert_Challan challan);
```

here is my service.svc.cs implementation:

```
public string Insert_ChallanDetails(Insert_Challan challan)
{
    string Message;
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connection_string);
    conn.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Voilation (Name,Voilation_place,Home_address,Licence_No,Place_issue,Reg_no,Offence1,Offence2,Offence3,Penalty1,Penalty2,Penalty3,Rs)VALUES (@Name,@Voilation_Place,@Address,@Licence_No,@Location,@Registration_No,@Offence_Code_1,@Offence_Code_2,@Offence_Code_3,@Penalty_1,@Penalty_2,@Penalty_3,@Total)", conn);
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Name",System.Data.SqlDbType.Text).Value=challan.NAME;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Voilation_Place", System.Data.SqlDbType.Text).Value = challan.VIOLATION_PALCE;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Address", System.Data.SqlDbType.Text).Value = challan.ADDRESS;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Licence_No", System.Data.SqlDbType.Text).Value = challan.LICENCE_NO;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Location",System.Data.SqlDbType.Text).Value=challan.LOCATION;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Registration_No", System.Data.SqlDbType.Text).Value = challan.REGISTRATION_NO;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Offence_Code_1",System.Data.SqlDbType.Text).Value=challan.OFFENCE_CODE_1;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Offence_Code_2", System.Data.SqlDbType.Text).Value = challan.OFFENCE_CODE_2;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Offence_Code_3", System.Data.SqlDbType.Text).Value = challan.OFFENCE_CODE_3;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Penalty_1", System.Data.SqlDbType.Money).Value = challan.PENALTY_1;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Penalty_2", System.Data.SqlDbType.Money).Value = challan.PENALTY_2;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Penalty_3", System.Data.SqlDbType.Money).Value = challan.PENALTY_3;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Total", System.Data.SqlDbType.Money).Value = challan.TOTAL;
    int result = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
   if(result==1)
   {
       Message = challan.NAME + "Challan Inserted Sucessfully";
   }
   else
   {
       Message = challan.NAME + "Challan Could not be Inserted";
   }
    return Message;
}
```

and here is my button click event in wp8:

```
private void submit_button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        Insert_Challan challanInfo = new Insert_Challan();
        challanInfo.NAME = Name_Text.Text;
        challanInfo.LOCATION = Location_text.Text;
        challanInfo.ADDRESS = address_text.Text;
        challanInfo.LICENCE_NO = Licence_text.Text;
        challanInfo.VIOLATION_PALCE = IssuePlace_text.Text;
        challanInfo.REGISTRATION_NO = RegNo_text.Text;
        challanInfo.OFFENCE_CODE_1 = code1_text.Text;
        challanInfo.OFFENCE_CODE_2 = code2_text.Text;
        challanInfo.OFFENCE_CODE_3 = code3_text.Text;
        challanInfo.PENALTY_1 = decimal.Parse(Penalty_1.Text);
        challanInfo.PENALTY_2 = decimal.Parse(Penalty_2.Text);
        challanInfo.PENALTY_3 = decimal.Parse(Penalty_3.Text);
        challanInfo.TOTAL = decimal.Parse(total_text.Text);
        try
        {
            service.Insert_ChallanDetailsCompleted += new EventHandler<Insert_ChallanDetailsCompletedEventArgs>(service_Insert_ChallanDetailsCompleted);
            service.Insert_ChallanDetailsAsync(challanInfo);

        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex+"");
        }
        //service.Insert_ChallanDetailsCompleted += new EventHandler<Insert_ChallanDetailsCompletedEventArgs>(service_Insert_ChallanDetailsCompleted);
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        throw (ex);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you look at the `InnerException` property of the TargetInvocationException to see what the cause of this exception is?

Comment: in the disassembly i found: System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.Invoke() 706F3A12  call        704C0DF8

Comment: That looks like the source of the `TargetInvocationException`, but not the cause of it. As far as I know the `TargetInvocationException` is always thrown because the method implementation threw an exception. That's why I wanted you to look at the content of its `InnerException`.

An alternative is to wrap your `Insert_ChallanDetails` in a `try catch` and inspect the exception from there.

Comment: sir i used try catch but it did'nt work.....at somewhere i found that the exception might b coz of service.Insert_ChallanAsync(challan).....bt i m nt getting whats the problem in using Async